# Problem recovering django with pipenv after crash

Tags: django, pipenv

I recently had a catastrophic hard drive failure and I had not pushed all of my recent commits to a remote repository (I have learned my lesson). Fortunately I did have a copy of most of my latest work.

I recreated my local environment (I thought correctly but maybe not) and attempted to start the project with the files. When I run "pipenv shell" the env appears to activate and running "git branch" does show the two branches. However when I ran "python manage.py migrate" I received the following error:

```
(sitefolder) user@users-MBP ohive % python manage.py migrate
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I run "python -V" it returns 2.7.18. The python version should be 3.9.6. When I do start pipenv shell in a folder without the old files, the correct version is returned.

Any ideas about how I can get the pipenv to use the correct version of python?

Comment: What if you run `python3 manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Are you sure you activated the correct virtual environment?

Comment: I tried python3 manage.py and received an error that Django could not be imported. I then tried running "pipenv install -r requirements.txt" and received an error that ended with: 
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Desktop/sitename/.venv/bin/python'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recreated my local environment (I thought correctly but maybe not) and attempted to start the project with the files.

You probably made a virtual environment with [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) as interpreter, you can construct one with:

```
pipenv --python 3
```